# Centering in matrices

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I am building a big matrix within the which I have block matrices, which I want to indicate by boxes. My current state looks like this:

```
 $$\begin{matrix} \framebox[3.\width]{J}& \begin{matrix} 0&0&\\0&0&\end{matrix}&\\
    \begin{matrix} 0&0&\\0&0&\end{matrix}& \framebox[3.\width]{J}&\end{matrix}$$
```

but this makes the frameboxes aligned to the right. I want them centered in their matrix-cell.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It would be very helpful if you could provide a complete [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/32374) beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Why don't you just write `J&0\\0&J`?

Comment: I want to insert the full 0-matrices to make clear, that J is 2x2

Comment: You can say so via `J_{2\times 2}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The columns are centred, but each of your 'inner' matrices has an empty column, generated by a spurious `&` at the end of the row. Delete these, and the problem goes away.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
\framebox[3.\width]{J} &
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
& \\
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
& \framebox[3.\width]{J} &
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]